# subprocess.call not working with locked screen on Windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, logout

I wrote a Python script that automatically logs out of my Windows PC (running Windows 7). I do this via `subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/l"])`.

This was working a few weeks ago even when the screen was locked, but now it doesn't work when the screen is locked. I don't know what changed: the code is the same.

Is there a way I can make sure that function works even when the screen is locked?

Comment: and (a bit more info not included in my question above)... the logout function works when the screen is *unlocked*, just not when it is locked.

Comment: How are you running your script?

Comment: Either through a GUI (tkinter) or via Spyder.

Comment: …but your machine is locked. What causes your script to run when your machine is locked?

Comment: I have a timer in the code, set to run the code at a specific time.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the timer code you're using.